MUI Select label does not properly fit on focus
I am using MUI Select component, the problem I'm having is that label doesn't fit on focus and starts to overlap with the dropdown field itself as in a screenshot below:

How can I fix this issue so that label on each dropdown is sized properly on focus, regardless of the label text length?
Below is the code snippet:
<FormControl
    sx={{
        width: "100%",
        "& .MuiOutlinedInput-root": {
            "&.Mui-focused fieldset": {
                borderColor: "#a6a8a7",
            },
        },
    }}
>
    <InputLabel
    sx={{
        fontSize: "13px",
        "&.Mui-focused": {
            color: "black",
            fontSize: "14px",
        },
    }}>
        Please select the reason for declining the request:
    </InputLabel>
    <Select
        label="Please select the reason for declining the request:"
    >
        <MenuItem value={1}>Redirect to another person</MenuItem>
    </Select>
</FormControl>                            

I've tried to adjust width on the notched outline but that doesn't seam to change anything:
"& .MuiInputBase-root.Mui-focused .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline":
                                       {
                                           width: "auto",
                                       },

I don't have this issue with the TextField, only with the Select.
Thank you for your time!

If you're changing the fontSize of InputLabel, add the fontSize in Select sx prop as well. Check the updated code below:
<FormControl
    fullWidth
    sx={{
      '& .MuiOutlinedInput-root': {
        '&.Mui-focused fieldset': { borderColor: '#a6a8a7' },
      },
    }}
  >
    <InputLabel
      id="my-label-id"
      sx={{
        fontSize: 14,
        '&.Mui-focused': { color: 'black' },
      }}
    >
      Please select the reason for declining the request:
    </InputLabel>
    <Select labelId="my-label-id" label="Please select the reason for declining the request:" sx={{ fontSize: 14 }}>
      <MenuItem value={1}>Redirect to another person</MenuItem>
    </Select>
</FormControl>

Few improvements:

You can use fullWidth prop instead of {width: '100%'} in FormControl.
You don't need to add "px" in font size. Just write the number like this fontSize: 14. MUI by default, treats number as px font size.
Removed font size inside '&.Mui-focused': { color: 'black' },.
Added id="my-label-id" to <InputLabel> and same id shared labelId="my-label-id" in <Select>


Simran Singh thank you so much, this solved my problem!! And thank you for the other suggestions!
